# Need the Now Function set in another cell when copying data from Macro

Tags: excel, cell

I have this macro which takes data from the Clipboard and paste it into an specific cell transposing some information.

```
Sub UpdateData()

        '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

      With ws
        '~~> Using this as you are copying it from Notepad~~~~
        .Activate
        .Range("H1").Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H1" & ",H3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

'~~Clear data content~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Range("H1:H10").ClearContents

End With

End Sub
```

I need this macro to update the cell B next to the line updated (C) with the NOW  formula.

I have this other macro which updates the Row B whenever the Row C is updated, but they're not working together.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.MoveAfterReturn = True
If Target.Count = 1 Then
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C1000")) Is Nothing Then
    Cells(Target.Row, "B") = Now
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how should I do it?

Comment: `Cells(Target.Row, "B").Formula = "=NOW()"`

Answer (score 0):

The **Target** is the cell or cells that have changed and triggered the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. In your case, this is multiple cells so you have to deal with each individually.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.MoveAfterReturn = True
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C1000")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C1000"))
            Cells(c.Row, "B") = Now
        Next c
      End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Turn off event handling while you are changing data (adding a timerstamp) to the worksheet or you will trigger the Worksheet_Change to run on top of itself.

After determining that one or more cells in the C1:C1000 range has been altered, the [For Each ... Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) cycles through each cell and deposits a timestamp on that row's column B.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What if I change the target from C1;C1000 to H1? Which in the first time is pasted from the clipboard in the macro UpdateData? Another thing, both macros work fine individually, but when I try to unify them so when I trigger UpdateData it fills the cells C and D paste the NOW result in the cell B. They don't work

Comment: tbh, I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish with that other procedure. When you use `.Range("H1" & ",H3")` are you trying to copy H1, H2 & H3 or just H1 & H3? The string concatenation is completely unnecessary. Further, you transpose the paste which should put it into a single row but you are trying to pick up changes to column C all in one column. I'm having a hard time bending my head around **exactly** what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is an example of what I need. We receive a list of data, username; userid; gpn; country. This fields are copied to the clipboard from another application like a list. so in H1 you have username, H2 userid, H3 gpn, H4 country. We only need the username in the C cell and the GPN in the D cell next to it. Thats what the macro Update data does. and I need it to set the timestamp using the NOW function in the B cell when it copies the data to the C and D cells. Is this more clear? sorry